# My friend can’t see my real email address, they see a weird “username@PUBLIC.TALK.GOOGLE.COM”. How can I get back my email address?

Tags: google-talk

I didn’t notice until a friend tried to send me an email directly from Gtalk, but the email address he sees on my information was a weird code plus `@PUBLIC.TALK.GOOGLE.COM`. I asked to some other friend and they also can’t see my Gmail address nor sending me emails, because the weird email doesn’t work.

How can I get back my Gmail in the Gtalk information that my friends see about me?

Comment: The Google Talk app for Windows was shut down on February 23, 2015.